# how to apply like operator for Integer in hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate

I want to apply like operator to an Integer by using the criteria API of Hibernate

```
Ex:from User where str(id) like :id
```

It works using HQL, but I want to write the same query using the Hibernate criteria API.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is `sqlRestriction`. You can not use criteria restrictions. Try the following:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" id LIKE '%"+yourIdForSearching+"%' "));
List<User> users = criteria.list();
```

Comment: It could be required to explicitely cast the id to a string to allow the comparison with LIKE. This was required in my case using PostgreSQL: `"id::text LIKE '"+yourIdForSearching+"%'` (also dont forget the ' around the search expression.